# Sorting news api endpoint

Tags: kotlin, sorting, pagination, retrofit

My task is to sort everything and top headlines articles at the same click.

I'm using this news api: https://newsapi.org/

My endpoints at the moment:

```
@GET("top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=${BuildConfig.API_KEY}")
suspend fun getTopHeadlinesArticles(
    @Query("page")  page:Int = 1
) : Response<ArticleListResponse>

@GET("everything?q=tesla&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${BuildConfig.API_KEY}")
suspend fun getAllArticles(
    @Query("page") page: Int = 1
) : Response<ArticleListResponse>
```

Problem with sortBy is that it only is available in everything endpoint if I use it in top headlines it does nothing. I tried with sortBy=publishedAt and -publishedAt.

Json example:

```
"status": "ok",
"totalResults": 37,
"articles": [

    {
        "source": {
            "id": "reuters",
            "name": "Reuters"
        },
        "author": null,
        "title": "Russia says it resumes participation in Ukraine grain deal - Reuters.com",
        "description": "Russia said on Wednesday it would resume its participation in a deal to free up vital grain exports from war-torn Ukraine after suspending it over the weekend in a move that had threatened to exacerbate hunger across the world.",
        "url": "https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/grain-ships-sail-ukraine-ports-russian-missiles-knock-out-power-across-country-2022-10-31/",
        "urlToImage": "https://www.reuters.com/resizer/0q0d5ZOWPFOkR2Yc_Mbv8TQZrAA=/1200x628/smart/filters:quality(80)/cloudfront-us-east-2.images.arcpublishing.com/reuters/NQYU2CZKHRNKRDPQ76IQYOV2DE.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2022-11-02T10:43:00Z",
        "content": "ANKARA/MYKOLAIV, Ukraine, Nov 2 (Reuters) - Russia said on Wednesday it would resume its participation in a deal to free up vital grain exports from war-torn Ukraine after suspending it over the week… [+2828 chars]"
```

From news api documentation: Articles are sorted by the earliest date published first.

I want to sort it ascending and descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `top-headlines` endpoint's [documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) lists all the possible request parameters, and none of them control the sorting. So, unfortunately, it's not possible to change the sorting for this endpoint. You can try submitting a feature request to them by sending an email to support@newsapi.org.